# Details Log on IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, logging, iis-8.5, wcf

On my IIS log I found errors that occur randomly when a client calls my WCF service.

The error log is this:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-12-13 10:21:27
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-12-13 10:21:27 [MYSERVERIP] POST /MyService/Service.svc - 443 - [CLIENTIP] IBM+WebServices/1.0 - 500 0 64 328
```

It seems that in some situations the call to the service returns error 500.

From my tests I was not able to reproduce the error, the only thing I understood is that the service code is not executed. The error is raised before.

I wanted to know if there's a way on IIS to get a more detailed error log and figure out what it might depend on.

I tried to set the "FailedReqLogFiles" but nothing is tracked.

Comment: WCF 500 requires its own tracing https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: Now, from Windows Event Viewer i found errors TLS with code 20 (bad_record_mac) and 42 (bad_certificate). But they occurs only for some service calls. What can it depend on?